# Android : Object retrieved from Service is null after binding service as well

Tags: java, android, service

I am working on an Android application in which I am connecting to a service and wish to access the object inside it. The same mechanism is working for one class, and failing for other one with a NPE. I don't know why and what is going wrong. Any help would be nice.

Error log :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
    {mycompany.notes/mycompany.notes.Activity.ChatMessagesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient mycompany.notes.Activity.ConsoleChatClient.client' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient mycompany.notes.Activity.ConsoleChatClient.client' on a null object reference
    at mycompany.notes.Activity.ChatMessagesActivity.onCreate(ChatMessagesActivity.java:177)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
```

Service Code :

```
public class ConsoleChatClient extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    BayeuxClient client;
    HttpClient httpClient = StaticRestTemplate.getHttpClient();
    String defaultURL = StaticRestTemplate.baseURL + "/cometd";


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        ConsoleChatClient getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return ConsoleChatClient.this;
        }
    }

    private void connectionEstablished() {
        System.err.printf("system: Connection to Server Opened%n");

    }

    private void connectionClosed() {
        System.err.printf("system: Connection to Server Closed%n");
    }

    private void connectionBroken() {
        System.err.printf("system: Connection to Server Broken%n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        performConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        performConnection();
        return mBinder;

    }



 private void performConnection() {
        try {
            httpClient.start();
            ClientTransport clientTransport = new LongPollingTransport(null, httpClient);
            bayeuxClient = new BayeuxClient(defaultURL, clientTransport);
            // Below for use with Spring-Security post-login.
            bayeuxClient.putCookie(new HttpCookie("JSESSIONID", StaticRestTemplate.getJsessionid()));
            bayeuxClient.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener(new InitializerListener());
            bayeuxClient.getChannel(Channel.META_CONNECT).addListener(new ConnectionListener());
            bayeuxClient.handshake();
            StaticRestTemplate.setClient(bayeuxClient);
            StaticRestTemplate.setHttpClient(httpClient);
            boolean success = bayeuxClient.waitFor(2000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);
            if (!success) {
                System.err.printf("Could not handshake with server at %s%n", defaultURL);
            }else {
                System.err.printf("Handhskare complete");
            }

        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
    }
```

ChatMessagesActivity.java :

```
public class ChatMessagesActivity extends ApplicationDrawerLoader {

    HttpClient httpClient;
    ConsoleChatClient consoleChatClient;
    boolean mBound = false;

    private ChatListener chatListener = new ChatListener();

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConsoleChatClient.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_IMPORTANT);
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            ConsoleChatClient.LocalBinder binder = (ConsoleChatClient.LocalBinder) service;
            consoleChatClient = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;

            if (conversationId != 0) {
                consoleChatClient.client.getChannel("/person/" + conversationId).unsubscribe();
            }

            if (groupAccountId != 0) {
                consoleChatClient.client.getChannel("/chat/" + conversationId).unsubscribe();
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_messages);

  try {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConsoleChatClient.class);
            startService(intent);
            httpClient = consoleChatClient.httpClient;
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

// Below code crashes at consoleChatClient.client
 if (conversationId != 0) {
            consoleChatClient.client.getChannel("/person/" + conversationId).subscribe(chatListener);
        }

        if (groupAccountId != 0) {
            consoleChatClient.client.getChannel("/chat/" + conversationId).subscribe(chatListener);
        }
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong that it works in one class, and not in other. Any help. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you initializing the `client` instance variable?

Comment: `httpClient = consoleChatClient.httpClient;` here `consoleChatClient` is null

Comment: @pskink : Actually no, httpClient is not null, the BayeuxClient is null. That's what is confusing me, I just confirmed that.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney : It's instantiated in performConnection. I can paste the code for it if you want.

Comment: what is ChatMessagesActivity.java line 177 ? you have NPE there...

Comment: @pskink :             consoleChatClient.client.getChannel("/chat/" + conversationId).subscribe(chatListener); . the client part in it is null is the complain. client = BayeuxClient. I will refactor my code for future clarity.

Comment: @WeareBorg Would you mind posting the code for `performConnection`?

Comment: @pskink : I have put all the 3 java files in pastebin. 1st : http://pastebin.com/GXNm6BuE  2nd : http://pastebin.com/fN8uq8d6  3rd :  http://pastebin.com/fRvwpWXB    . The problem statement is still the same, Service is working with one class, and not with other. I have made some changes, but the subscription code in ChatMessagesActivity is dysfunctional.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney : I have added the code as well as all the files in pastebin in above comment. Kindly have a look. Thank you. :-)

Comment: basically you cannot access `consoleChatClient` before `onServiceConnected` is called (this is the only place where it is set `consoleChatClient = binder.getService();`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `bindService()` right after after `startService()`, because `onStart()` is executed later. Binding is not immediate, so wait for `onServiceConnected()` to
start working with your `consoleChatClient` instead of doing it right after `startService()`. This guarantees that it will be properly initialized.

Also, you might want to unbind using `getApplicationContext().unbindService()`, since using your activity's context may not work.

Here's how I would do it:

```
public class ChatMessagesActivity extends ApplicationDrawerLoader {

    HttpClient httpClient;
    ConsoleChatClient consoleChatClient;
    boolean mBound = false;

    private ChatListener chatListener = new ChatListener();

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConsoleChatClient.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_IMPORTANT);
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            ConsoleChatClient.LocalBinder binder = (ConsoleChatClient.LocalBinder) service;
            consoleChatClient = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
            onConsoleChatClientReady()
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;

            if (conversationId != 0) {
                consoleChatClient.client.getChannel("/person/" + conversationId).unsubscribe();
            }

            if (groupAccountId != 0) {
                consoleChatClient.client.getChannel("/chat/" + conversationId).unsubscribe();
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_messages);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConsoleChatClient.class);
        startService(intent);


    }

    private void onConsoleChatReady(){
        httpClient = consoleChatClient.httpClient;
        if (conversationId != 0) {
        consoleChatClient.client.getChannel("/person/" + conversationId).subscribe(chatListener);
        }

        if (groupAccountId != 0) {
        consoleChatClient.client.getChannel("/chat/" + conversationId).subscribe(chatListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I wait for onServiceConnected ?? Thanks

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.. :-) I am having one final error about updating a List directly for new message. I will post the link here once I post the question. Thanks a lot .. :-)